# Python Currency string conversion to float

Tags: python, currency

This is the list:

```
x = ["111,222","111.222","111,222.11","111.222,11","111111","111.22"]
```

I would like that it will convert correctly without using locale and will work with the set above as the original data set is a mess

I have tried

- regex
- `float("".join(["".join([i for i in list(s)[0:-3] if i not in [".",","]]),"".join(list(s)[-3:]).replace(",",".")]) if list(s)[-3] in [".",","] else "".join(list(s)))`
- `r = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', s) export = float(r[0:-2]+'.'+r[-2:])`
- ```
     comma = ","
     dot = "."

     last_comma_index = s.rfind(comma)
     last_dot_index = s.rfind(dot)

     if last_comma_index > last_dot_index:
         last_index = last_comma_index
     else:
         last_index = last_dot_index

     before_point = s[:last_index]

     no_commas = "".join(before_point.split(comma))
     no_dots = "".join(no_commas.split(dot))

     export  = no_dots + dot + s[last_index + 1:]
  ```
- ```
         s = "".join(c for c in s if c.isdigit() or c in [",", "."])

         if "," in s:
             decimal_sep = ","
             thousands_sep = "."
         else:
             decimal_sep = "."
             thousands_sep = ","

         s = s.replace(decimal_sep, ".")
         s = re.sub(f"\\{thousands_sep}(?=[0-9])", "", s)
         export = s
  ```
- ```
         def parseNumber(text):

         try:
             # First we return None if we don't have something in the text:
             if text is None:
                 return None
             if isinstance(text, int) or isinstance(text, float):
                 return text
             text = text.strip()
             if text == "":
                 return None
             # Next we get the first "[0-9,. ]+":
             n = re.search("-?[0-9]*([,. ]?[0-9]+)+", text).group(0)
             n = n.strip()
             if not re.match(".*[0-9]+.*", text):
                 return None
             # Then we cut to keep only 2 symbols:
             while " " in n and "," in n and "." in n:
                 index = max(n.rfind(','), n.rfind(' '), n.rfind('.'))
                 n = n[0:index]
             n = n.strip()
             # We count the number of symbols:
             symbolsCount = 0
             for current in [" ", ",", "."]:
                 if current in n:
                     symbolsCount += 1
             # If we don't have any symbol, we do nothing:
             if symbolsCount == 0:
                 pass
             # With one symbol:
             elif symbolsCount == 1:
                 # If this is a space, we just remove all:
                 if " " in n:
                     n = n.replace(" ", "")
                 # Else we set it as a "." if one occurence, or remove it:
                 else:
                     theSymbol = "," if "," in n else "."
                     if n.count(theSymbol) > 1:
                         n = n.replace(theSymbol, "")
                     else:
                         n = n.replace(theSymbol, ".")
             else:
                 # Now replace symbols so the right symbol is "." and all left are "":
                 rightSymbolIndex = max(n.rfind(','), n.rfind(' '), n.rfind('.'))
                 rightSymbol = n[rightSymbolIndex:rightSymbolIndex+1]
                 if rightSymbol == " ":
                     return parseNumber(n.replace(" ", "_"))
                 n = n.replace(rightSymbol, "R")
                 leftSymbolIndex = max(n.rfind(','), n.rfind(' '), n.rfind('.'))
                 leftSymbol = n[leftSymbolIndex:leftSymbolIndex+1]
                 n = n.replace(leftSymbol, "L")
                 n = n.replace("L", "")
                 n = n.replace("R", ".")
             # And we cast the text to float or int:
             n = float(n)

             if n > 5000000:
                 return 0
             elif n.is_integer():
                 return int(n)
             else:
                 return n

         except: pass

         return None
  ```
- Decimal
- locale

  - Most of the answers in StackOverflow in around locale but have to avoid it as data messed up...

The result should be like this:

```
x = [111222,111222,111222.11,111222.11,111111,111.22]
```

Looking forward for any suggestions.

Comment: You've shown us what you've tried, but what went wrong with each case? What was the result versus what you were expecting?

Comment: E.g. the best one if code 3 (starts with comma = ), but it is failed completely with "111111", + causing other issues....

Comment: Not as clever to handle all variations :(

Comment: I suggest being more thorough and detailed in your description of exactly what went wrong, and include that info in the post rather than in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the commas with dots so that the separators are all the same, then split on the separator and check if the rightmost chunk is of length 3.

Since no currencies (that I know of) use three decimal places for their fractional amounts, if the right chunk is of length 3, it must be part of a whole number.  Otherwise it must be part a float.

```
x = ["111,222","111.222","111,222.11","111.222,11","111111","111.22"]

def from_currency(x: str):
    x = x.replace(',', '.')
    if not x.count('.'):
        return int(x)
    *whole_parts, frac = x.split('.')
    if len(frac) == 3:
        return int(''.join([*whole_parts, frac]))
    else:
        whole = ''.join(whole_parts)
        return float(f'{whole}.{frac}')


[from_currency(c) for c in x]
# returns 
[111222,
 111222,
 111222.11,
 111222.11,
 111111,
 111.22]
```

Comment: Will you be able to explain in a bit more detail so it will be clear what have you done?

Comment: Added some details.